# Azure Search Service built-in OCR skill performing worse than Cognitive Service standalone OCR

Tags: azure, ocr, azure-cognitive-search

I tried to create pdf AI-enrichment pipeline using indexer from **Azure Search Service** following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-quickstart-blob. I used **built-in OCR skill** just like in the example.
This solution (particularly OCR) did **not** perform as well as I hoped it to.

I decided to isolate and test just the OCR step and potentially find a way to improve it. I run plain, standalone OCR from Cognitive Services - Computer Vision. As far as I understand there should be no difference between these two OCRs since Azure Search Service uses  the same OCR from Cognitive Services.

Surprisingly, the OCR used in Azure Search Service did worse (quite significantly) than the one from Cognitive Services - Computer Vision.

Both OCRs were run on the same test pdfs. Simplest one (single page pdf with texts as images) shown below (different formats of results should be irrelevant):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQceZ.png)

Output from Azure Search Service indexer:

```
"\nThis is a normal test text. It does not need OCR \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n This is a text 2. Text size vs image size 2. This is a text 2. Text size vs image size 2. \n\n This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4. This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4. This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4. This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4. \n\n This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size. This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size .| \n\n\n"
```

Output from Azure Cognitive Services - Computer Vision OCR:

```
"This is a normal test text. It does not need OCR",
"This is a text 1. Text size vs image size 1.",
"This is a text 2. Text size vs image size 2.",
"This is a text 2. Text size vs image size 2.",
"This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4.",
"This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4.",
"This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4.",
"This is a text 3. Text size vs image size 4.",
"This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size. This is",
"a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text",
"4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4.",
"Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text",
"size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size",
"vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs image size . This is a text 4. Text size vs",
"image size ."
```

As can be seen the OCR from Search Service completely missed text 1.

I am not sure where this difference is coming from. My guess is that OCR from Cognitive Services treats whole page as a single image while OCR from Search Service extracts images embedded in pdf format, processes them separately and struggles when text is simply too big in a given image. **Is this a good direction? If so how can I handle such cases with Search Service indexer?**

Answer (score -1):

Object character recognition is having a pattern in identifying the characters of each and every input. We will get differences in the form of special characters. Some cases the images and special characters are different to access. Checkout the impact of the input and recognition using vision studio.

[image]

[image]

In the first image the text is there on the shirt, but the text is not recognized. In the second image text is recognized and symbols are not recognized. By default, some of the symbols and special characters are not trained in cognitive services OCR and vision studio. That is the reason for inaccuracy in identification.